# Member of a closed group can comment but CANNOT post

Tags: facebook-groups

Members of a closed group can comment on others' posts but CANNOT post their own, despite the fact that (being the administrator) I went to https://www.facebook.com/groups/1631900363551085/edit/ and under "Story Posting Permissions" I checked "Αnyone in the group". What is the problem and how can I fix it?